# Disable Safari 7.0.2 keychain password save

Tags: javascript, html, safari

How can I disable safari from saving a user/pass from a form using html or javascript?
I've had this issue that came up with safari 7.0.2 where you can save a user/pass to a keychain and when you goto that same form it automatically overrides those fields?  Personally I think this is horrible behavior.  I don't think fields should ever be overridden.

I've created an isolated version that you can demo the issue here.
http://dev.davidsalazar.com/issues/safari-autofill/

Steps to replicate (ensure you use latest safari 7.0.2)

1. Type and user/pass click save. It should prompt you to save to keychain, accept the save.
2. Now click on the link load random data and you will notice that safari will now be overriding those fields with your perviously saved fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround: create another (fake) password field and Safari is probably confused by it - autofill will be "disabled" in this case

tested in Safari 7.0.2 and 7.0.3

demo (with red fake password): http://js.pejsa.info/~jam/safari-autofill/

`<form method="post" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="abc" />
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="def" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit_btn" value="Save" />
    <input type="password" id="fakePassword" 
        style="border:0;width:10px;height:10px;background-color:red;" />
</form>`

Comment: You're right this is a good hack until they fix it. I'm using these styles inside a dummy password.


`display: inline; width: 0; height: 0; border: 0;`

Comment: i still can't believe they safari hasn't fix this bug lol. WTH is their problem.

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible due to new behavior in all browsers - autocomplete="off" is now ignored

for details see http://raesene.github.io/blog/2014/04/17/changing-times-the-end-of-autocomplete-equals-off/

Answer (score 0):

i search this problem before day for my project. and finally i found the solution wit plug-in below.

this plug-in work structure like this. It get your input and clone it. 
Use this clone and create same input properties and clone it another hidden input. After that remove your orginal input and put hidden and cloned input same position.

It's reason that. Modern browser (has keychain) control input (type password) when page loaded and mapped over DOM. After page load plug-in get input and clone and remove orginal input. this operation changes DOM mapping. So brovser cannot access this control when page redirect. So don't suggest yo to save password.

You can use this plug-in for this problem.

Notes:

1. If you use another plug-in like me. Forexample jquery-keyboard plug-in for password secure enter. you shoul modify your initkeyboard method. becasue keyboard control your input and init near this input. you could change this init method like below

init keyboard changing

before

```
var _inputwidth = $(elm).parent().find('input').width();
```

after
    var _inputwidth = $(elm).parent().find('input[type=text],input[type=password]').width();

because plug-in output like this

```
<input type="hidden"  id="txtPass" name="txtPass" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off">
<input type="text"  id="txtPass" name="txtPass" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off">
```

2. If you have any keypress or keydown event initialize for this input put this codes after plug-in init. because this plug-in change DOM mapping

this plug-in usage like below

```
$('input[type=password]').disableAutocomplete();
```

this is creator desctiption

> This jQuery plug-in enforces the autocomplete=off HTML attribute on
>   password (and other) fields. Recent browsers have chosen to ignore
>   this attribute in favor of user preferences. However, some financial
>   (and other) institutions may have good reasons to enforce this
>   practice.
>
> [jQouery Disable AutoComplete](http://plugins.jquery.com/disable-autocomplete/)

---

Old comment
I have a page with 2 inputs. one of these input type password, other text (username password form). Safari doesn't work with autocomplete="off". I use for this problem two inline hidden input. These inputs have generic names as below. My original username password input has different name so Safari first looks for a keychain to get or set these inputs. You can use this solution to prevent Safari using a keychain for your secure page.

```
<input type="text" name="Username" style="display:none;"/>
<input type="password" name="Password" style="display:none;" />
```